# SQLAchemy error when selecting specific columns from table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to select specific columns in SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table    

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///client.db')
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

lc = Table('lc', metadata, autoload=True)

cached = lc.select([lc.c.start, lc.c.end]).execute()
```

I am getting this error when I try and run the code above:

```
    "SQL expression object or string expected."
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Table.select` accepts only a where clause. For specific columns you should use `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select`

```
from sqlalchemy import select

q = select((lc.c.start, lc.c.end), lc.c.start==<date>)
```